# create an m file for sin signa

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to create an m-file function for a sine signal with input **tmin, tmax, time-period, amplitude**, but I don't know how to to begin. I am a newbie with Matlab.

My Sine function has the following code

```
function  y=sin(x)

y=sin(x);
```

In the command window, I type `plot(mysine(x));` to get the sine signal, but this is all I know.

How do you set the **tmin, tmax, time-period, amplitude** ?

I want to have something like this

```
[x] = mysine(-10,10,0.25,2);
plot(x);
```

Comment: This is not a matlab question, this is a math question. If you don't understand how a frequency or a time period, or amplitude enters when using `sin` you should open a textbook. Even Wikipedia can answer this... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I really wanted to see an example.

Comment: Check my answer, but you should really be solving homework yourself.

Comment: It is recommended to start with `function y = mysine(x,a,b,c,d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple question which isn't really to do with programming and I suspect it is homework.

if sine has the following form:

```
a*sin(b*x+c)+d

a affects the amplitude
b affects the time-period
c affects the phase
d affects the amplitude offset
```

Basically what you are wanting to do is this:

```
plot(tmin:timePeriod:tmax, amplitude*sin(tmin:timePeriod:tmax))
```

which will produce something like this:

[image]

Which is the sine form you are looking for I believe.

As a function:

```
function x = mysine(tmin, tmax, timePeriod, amplitude)
     x = plot(tmin:timePeriod:tmax, amplitude*sin(tmin:timePeriod:tmax))
end
```

Comment: Thank you Ben so much! Is it possible to convert it into an M File?

Comment: do you mean as a function. In which case yes, see the edited answer.

Comment: In the command line, what should I type to call this function. If I type ' plot(mysine(-2, 3, .1, 3))' it gives me an error saying "??? Output argument "x" (and maybe others) not assigned during call .." thanks!

Comment: I am getting no graph this time. On the command line I typed the following 'plot(mysine(-2, 3, .1, 3));' What exactly do I type there to call the function? Thanks for the replies!

Comment: You shouldnt need to write plot(mysine) the mysine function does the plotting. You need to do some more matlab tutorials.

Comment: Your right I definitely do. However, I got it working with 'mysine(-3, 3, .25, 3)' Question about the time period. Why when I type something like this ' mysine(-3, 3, pi, 3)' I get a straight line as for the graph?